Why can't I check the value of the state immediately after calling setState in function?
In my understanding, I under stand if there is only one setState but I'm confuse if I use setState two times and console.log two times in one function, the result will show the value before the first setState because the re-render will happen after the function that changes the state ends completely. However, in my code, when I activate the deleteTodo function, it calls the fetchTodo function and setIsLoading(true). Suddenly, the line {isLoading && <div>Loading...</div>} works, but when I try to console.log(isLoading), I find that it is still false. So, why does it work?
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const BASE_URL = "https://6763699d17ec5852cae8dc87.mockapi.io";

function App() {
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

  const fetchTodo = async () => {
    try {
      setIsLoading(true)
      const response = await axios.get(`${BASE_URL}/todo`);
      console.log(isLoading);
      setTodos(response.data);
      setIsLoading(false);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error: ", error.response);
    }
  };

  const deleteTodo = async (id) => {
    try {
      await axios.delete(`${BASE_URL}/todo/${id}`);
      await fetchTodo();
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error: ", error);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchTodo();
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      {isLoading && <div>Loading...</div>}
      {!isLoading && (
        <div>
          <div>Hello</div>
          {todos.map((todo, index) => (
            <div key={index}>
              {todo.id} {todo.name} {todo.status}
              <button>Edit</button>
              <button onClick={() => deleteTodo(todo.id)}>Delete</button>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      )}
    </>
  );
}

export default App;


Please correct me if my concept wrong
